# Let's give thanks

Tags: discussion, challenge

If [you](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/users) are reading this, there's [a good chance](http://www.gapminder.org/world/#$majorMode=chart$is;shi=t;ly=2003;lb=f;il=t;fs=11;al=30;stl=t;st=t;nsl=t;se=t$wst;tts=C$ts;sp=5.59290322580644;ti=2010$zpv;v=0$inc_x;mmid=XCOORDS;iid=phAwcNAVuyj1jiMAkmq1iMg;by=ind$inc_y;mmid=YCOORDS;iid=phAwcNAVuyj2tPLxKvvnNPA;by=ind$inc_s;uniValue=8.21;iid=phAwcNAVuyj0XOoBL_n5tAQ;by=ind$inc_c;uniValue=255;gid=CATID0;by=grp$map_x;scale=log;dataMin=295;dataMax=79210$map_y;scale=lin;dataMin=19;dataMax=86$map_s;sma=49;smi=2.65$cd;bd=0$inds=;example=75) that you are among the most fortunate human beings to walk the earth today.  So for the next *two* weeks (see below), let's ask questions around the theme of giving thanks.

Questions might touch on people who are thankful or on blessings and promises that ought to prompt us to be thankful.  Or you could simply ask questions about passages that you are thankful for.  The point is, we are blessed and most of us attribute that blessing to the God who is spoken of in the Bible.  Let us explore that idea these two weeks.

---

For non-USAians: Next Thursday is that most uniquely American of holidays: Thanksgiving.  Theoretically (and in my household), it is a day dedicated to giving thanks to our creator and sustainer who in His own unfathomable wisdom graced us with unwarranted blessings.  In practice, it tends to be a day dedicated to gluttony, sloth and crass commercialism.  (This year, stores are starting "Black Friday" on Thursday.  Unbelievable!)

For the rest of us: I imagine there will be less traffic this week as many of us will be travelling and spending time with family, so I think it would be a good plan to extend the challenge to two weeks.  Let's fight the trend of starting Holidays early, by extending this one late!

Comment: And football.  Don't forget the football.

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but I would be thankful (see what I did there?) if you would not use link-shortening services on StackExchange. They aren't necessary, and they prevent me from seeing where the link goes until I click on it.

Comment: @lonesomeday: No problem.  I didn't know that I'd used one.  (I just used the "Share Graph" link at gapminder.org.)  I'm not sure either link works the way I hoped however.